# selector .wrapper does not work, cannot wrap text on browser in css

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get the code in .wrapper{} to work. There is no change reflected on the browser. If the code in .wrapper{} works, the display on the browser should be repositioned closer to the centre.

Help needed: could someone point out the error in the code and suggest possible fixes?

```
/*index.html*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class= "wrapper">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1>Front page</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
/*style.css*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

ul {
     margin-left: 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block; /* changes from vertical dropdown to horizontal */
    line-height: 100px;
    
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:indianred;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li a:hover {
    
    font-family:monospace;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. With the margin commented out: https://jsfiddle.net/fu3azo7e/, with the margin applied: https://jsfiddle.net/fu3azo7e/1/ – clearly different.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out I think i was very unclear and modified my question! The main issue is that the code in .wrapper selector doesnt work. There are no changes in the browser even after .wrapper selector was added.

Comment: With wrapper: https://jsfiddle.net/fu3azo7e/ without wrapper: https://jsfiddle.net/d3t7masw/ Make the result window wide enough, then there is a _clear_ difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have made the .wrapper width 1000px. Try to change it or make half the width then you will find it into center or some changes.

**Note:**  You should put a clear visible background color like red or yellow to see your changes.

**fix it by replacing with this:**

```css
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;

}
```